# using this in json-styled javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Recently, I'm coding javascript with little knowledge of it.

And here's my first javascript code which written this morning.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    SubMenuHandler.init();
});

var SubMenuHandler = {
    init : function() {
        $("#statisticManager, #deviceManager, #policyManager").click(
            function(event) {
                var url = SubMenuHandler.getUrlFromEvent(event); // <-- These two
                SubMenuHandler.redirectPage(url);                // <-- lines
            }
        );
    },
    redirectPage : function(url) {
        $(location).attr("href", url);
    },
    getUrlFromEvent : function(event) {
        var target = event.target;
        var url = $(target).data("url");
        return url;
    }
}
```

As you can see, `SubMenuHandler` is called recursively in the class.

But, I don't see how this is done as good. From my experiences with other languages, they usually use the `this` keyword instead of using the full name of class, except when accessing static variables.

Is there similar or better way to do this job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
init : function() {
    var me = this; // <----- this is the magic
    $("#statisticManager, #deviceManager, #policyManager").click(
        function(event) {
            var url = me.getUrlFromEvent(event);

            me.redirectPage(url);
        }
    );
},
```

It is called "closures"

The random link from google: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/closures.shtml

And perfect answer here on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/111200/251311

Comment: I think you can replace `SubMenuHandler.getUrlFromEvent(event)` with `me.getUrlFromEvent(event)`

Comment: Thank you. Anyways, is there any class-scoped way to do that?